# Some frames come out blank when rendering animation

Tags: rendering, animation

[image: screenshot 1]

I’m trying to render a 250 frame test animation in Cycles at 30 fps. As export format I use .PNG. As for now from 10 images, only 4 came out properly, the other ones are just showing the HDRI background scene. What am I doing wrong?

It is a simple animation, a camera rotating around an object. The scene is kinda packed and rendering is using a lot of internal resources. Maybe that is the reason for this error? Here is a screenshot of the export folder.

[image: export folder]

Comment: You can bet that this is not normal intended behaviour. So just saying "I try to render an animation" is not very much information to find the problem, because generally you can render animations in Blender. Maybe you could explain more about your scene, what kind of animation, or is it a simulation etc., some screenshots maybe? Did you do it all by yourself or following some tutorial?

Comment: I did it myself. It is a very simple animation. I've added some screenshots now.

Comment: You'll get a better answer by making a bug report https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports